# Background fetch local notification using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

In my application I want to read local notification when the app is in background or killed and I want to cancel that notification since it is repeated.

I'm using the below code to schedule local notification,

```
let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate()
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
localNotification.alertBody = "Hello"
localNotification.userInfo = userInfo
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Two days later, I want to cancel that notification. So, I want to fetch the data and check the same to cancel it. There is no possibility to use `content-available=1` for a local notification and also I don't want user to interact with notification.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
}
```

Is there any possibility to background fetch local notification?

Comment: This question is nothing particularly to do with local notifications (as they can be cancelled using cancelLocalNotification) but with running in the background. There are many many past questions about running in the background you can look at. Short answer, no its not possible, unless your app is able to run in the background for some other legitimate reason

Answer (score 0):

Even if your device gets restart local notification will be in notification tray, it will not remove. when user will tap on notification and `didReceiveLocalNotification` will get call then only it will be under control to remove or for further task.

There is only possible way to do it with push kit notification, it will call remotely.

When it comes, it will invoke your app in background for 30 seconds then you will get control to access it to remove or do anything else.

Make sure if device gets restart you have to keep it in NSUserDefault unless you would not be able to access that object.